# Making Ajax output anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to output the ajax request anywhere within the body but it does not work when i move the target class to some other parent div. How can i target right element so it can show output where ever i want?

```js
$('.remotediv').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var projectContainer = $(this).closest('.projects-wrapper1, .projects-wrapper2, .projects-wrapper3').children('.ajax-container').attr('data-container');
  if ($('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]').hasClass('open-container')) {
    $('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]').addClass('closed-container');
    $('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]').removeClass('open-container');
  }
  var fileID = $(this).attr('data-project-file');
  if (fileID !== null) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]').offset().top - 59
    }, 500);
  }
  $('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]').load(fileID + " .project-body", function() {
    $('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]').addClass('open-container');
    $('.close-project').click(function() {
      $('.ajax-container').addClass('closed-container');
      $('.ajax-container').removeClass('open-container');
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#gallery-scroll').offset().top - 55
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.ajax-container').html('');
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="gallery-scroll"></div>
<div class="projects-wrapper1">
  <div data-project-file="/qa9z2ghv/show/" class="remotediv">
    <button> LOAD CONTENT </button>
  </div>

  <div data-container="container2" class="ajax-container">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

### Fiddle: <sup>(fiddle not loading link but it does show responce upon clicking loading content</sup>

https://jsfiddle.net/0Loyg6uj/

I want it to show output where ever i put `<div data-container="container2" class="ajax-container">&nbsp;</div>` inside `body`.

Comment: What are you expecting to get from this ajax call? And does this ajax call return its content successfully?

Comment: PLEASE CACHE THE OBJECT and no need fo jQuery() unless you have conflicts

Comment: @Andam yes this ajax call return request successfully but the problem is that it only work within the parent and childern div. i am trying to make it in the way so it can show output anywhere `ajax-container` div is placed.

Comment: So don't use closest. Give it an ID

Answer (score 0):

First to make your code more readable - something like this

```js
$('.remotediv').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var projectContainer = $(this).closest('.projects-wrapper').find('.ajax-container').attr('data-container');
  var $container = $('.ajax-container[data-container="' + projectContainer + '"]');
  $container.toggleClass('open-container closed-container');
  var fileID = $(this).attr('data-project-file');
  if (fileID !== null) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $container.offset().top - 59
    }, 500);
  }
  $container.load(fileID + " .project-body")
});
$('.ajax-container').on('click', '.close-project', function() {
  var $parent = $(this).closest('.ajax-container');
  $parent.toggleClass('closed-container open-container');
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#gallery-scroll').offset().top - 55
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $parent.html(''); // why empty???
  }, 1000);
});
```

Then extract the ajax container so we only have one and give it an ID

```js
 $('.remotediv').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var $container = $('#ajax-container');
   $container.toggleClass('open-container closed-container');
   var fileID = $(this).attr('data-project-file');
   if (fileID !== null) {
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $container.offset().top - 59
     }, 500);
   }
   $container.load(fileID + " .project-body")
 });
 $('#ajax-container').on('click', '.close-project', function() {
   var $parent = $(this).closest('div');
   $parent.toggleClass('closed-container open-container');
   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $('#gallery-scroll').offset().top - 55
   }, 500);
   setTimeout(function() {
     $parent.html(''); // why empty???
   }, 1000);
 });
```